# Is it possible to accept multiple data extensions for Journey Builder Custom Activity?

Tags: marketing-cloud, heroku, databinding

I have an Heroku app that binds to a specific Data Extension:

```
config.json
"inArguments":[
    { "firstName":"{{Contact.Attribute.__your-de-name__.FirstName}}"},
    { "lastName":"{{Contact.Attribute.__your-de-name__.LastName}}"},
    { "emailAddress": "{{Contact.Default.Email}}"}                          
],
```

Is it possible to make `__your-de-name__`  a variable, so that the same app can be used by multiple Journeys(different DE) at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a Data Extension you'll get the `External Key` which you can call as a variable.

It'll be available under the Data Extension properties and you can rename it to be something user friendly (like your DE name for an example). In system it's called `CustomerKey`.

More details on it in [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/dataextension.htm).

Comment: While this may answer the question, perhaps you could put in some more details? What is this External Key, where do you find it, etc? As written, it's a bit short as an answer.